# Cannot find lffi - Error linking with llvm libraries

Tags: llvm

I am trying to use LLVM as backend for my compiler, and while linking with the llvm libraries, I get this error

```
g++ obj/*.o `llvm-config --ldflags core jit native` `llvm-config --libs core jit native` -lfl -o Icarus
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lffi
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have installed llvm on my system and my cpp files compile fine. Its during linking that the library its searching can't be found.

Comment: I haven't used pkg-config before. I could look it up, but the same piece of code compiles and links fine with this current setup on my other system. And both system environments are the same. Any idea why this module is missing? and what is this module?

Comment: @AlexTheodoridis: Thanks! Installing libffi-dev solved the problem.

Comment: You can also build LLVM without FFI support, if don't need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If on a deb system try installing the dev libs, they solved the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Did you install libffi too?

ftp://sourceware.org/pub/libffi/libffi-3.0.10.tar.gz

I know that installing libffi into /usr prefix helped me, when ld complained about being unable to find -ffi